# crosstab and crossDataSet

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a crossTab with three lines and n columns. I used a CrosstabDataset and JRBeanCollectionDataSource to show my Data. My problem is I can only show the last object in my CollectionDataSource I don't have an access to the data in my crossDataSet.

NB:
I used JRDesignCrosstab (java Code) to create the crossTab.

```
    public static JRDesignCrosstab CrosstabPanel(String parameterName , JasperDesign jasperDesign, JRDesignDataset subDataset) throws JRException {

    // parameter
    JRDesignParameter parameter = new JRDesignParameter();
    parameter.setName(parameterName);
    parameter.setValueClass(java.lang.Object.class);
    jasperDesign.addParameter(parameter);
    subDataset.addParameter(parameter);

    //Gross Tab
    JRDesignCrosstab crosstab = new JRDesignCrosstab();
    crosstab.setX(-90);
    crosstab.setY(-4);
    crosstab.setWidth(600);
    crosstab.setHeight(400);
    //Expression :
    JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression("$P{"+parameterName+"}");

    //CrosstabDataset 
    JRDesignCrosstabDataset dataSet = new JRDesignCrosstabDataset();

    //datasetrun
    JRDesignDatasetRun dsr = new JRDesignDatasetRun();
    dsr.setDatasetName(subDataset.getName());
    dsr.setDataSourceExpression(expression);


    //datasetrun into CrosstabDataset
    dataSet.setResetType(ResetTypeEnum.NONE);
    dataSet.setDatasetRun(dsr);

    crosstab.setDataset(dataSet);


    //Bucket Row
    JRDesignCrosstabBucket bucket =  new JRDesignCrosstabBucket();
    JRDesignExpression expressionField = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionField.setText("$F{commissionSimPaye}");
    bucket.setValueClassName("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DataSource");
    bucket.setExpression(expressionField);

    //Row Group;
    JRDesignCrosstabRowGroup rowGroup = new JRDesignCrosstabRowGroup();
    rowGroup.setName("rowGroup");
    rowGroup.setBucket(bucket);
    rowGroup.setWidth(68*2+1);
    rowGroup.setTotalPosition(CrosstabTotalPositionEnum.END);
    crosstab.addRowGroup(rowGroup);

    //Bucket Second  Row
    bucket =  new JRDesignCrosstabBucket();
    expressionField = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionField.setText("$F{commissionSimPaye}");
    bucket.setValueClassName("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.ReportContext");
    bucket.setExpression(expressionField);

    //Row Group;
    rowGroup = new JRDesignCrosstabRowGroup();
    rowGroup.setName("secondRowGroup");
    rowGroup.setBucket(bucket);
    rowGroup.setWidth(68*2+1);
    rowGroup.setTotalPosition(CrosstabTotalPositionEnum.END);
    crosstab.addRowGroup(rowGroup);


    //Bucket Column
    bucket =  new JRDesignCrosstabBucket();
    expressionField = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionField.setText("$F{commissionSimCalcule}");
    bucket.setValueClassName("java.lang.Object");
    bucket.setExpression(expressionField);

    //ColumnGroup
    JRDesignCrosstabColumnGroup ColumnGroup = new JRDesignCrosstabColumnGroup();
    ColumnGroup.setName("columnGroup");
    ColumnGroup.setBucket(bucket);
    ColumnGroup.setHeight(60);
    ColumnGroup.setTotalPosition(CrosstabTotalPositionEnum.END);
    crosstab.addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup);


    JRDesignExpression expressionMesaure = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionMesaure.setText("$F{commissionSimCalcule}");
    JRDesignCrosstabMeasure measure = new JRDesignCrosstabMeasure();
    measure.setName("ColumContent"+0);
    measure.setValueExpression(expressionMesaure);
    measure.setValueClassName("java.lang.Object");
    crosstab.addMeasure(measure);

    expressionMesaure = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionMesaure.setText("$F{commissionSimPaye}");
    measure = new JRDesignCrosstabMeasure();
    measure.setName("ColumContent"+1);
    measure.setValueExpression(expressionMesaure);
    measure.setValueClassName("java.lang.Object");
    crosstab.addMeasure(measure);

    expressionMesaure = new JRDesignExpression();
    expressionMesaure.setText("$F{commissionSimAPaye}");
    measure = new JRDesignCrosstabMeasure();
    measure.setName("ColumContent"+2);
    measure.setValueExpression(expressionMesaure);
    measure.setValueClassName("java.lang.Object");
    crosstab.addMeasure(measure);

    //contenu de la cellule
    JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    JRDesignCrosstabCell cell = new JRDesignCrosstabCell();
    JRDesignExpression expressionTextField = new JRDesignExpression();
    JRDesignCellContents cellContents = new JRDesignCellContents();

        textField.setX(0);
        textField.setY(0);
        textField.setWidth(68);
        textField.setHeight(20);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.RIGHT);
        textField.getLineBox().getLeftPen().setLineWidth(1);
        textField.getLineBox().getTopPen().setLineWidth(1);
        textField.getLineBox().getRightPen().setLineWidth(1);
        textField.getLineBox().getBottomPen().setLineWidth(1);
        cell.setHeight(20);
        cell.setWidth(68);
        expressionTextField.setText("$V{ColumContent"+0+"}");
        textField.setExpression(expressionTextField);
        cellContents.addElement(textField);
        cell.setContents(cellContents);
        crosstab.addCell(cell);
    return crosstab;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved,  I worked on the structure of JRBeanCollectionDataSource